# Notify backend whenever user enters/exits a region

Tags: ios, iphone

So it seems I can set up regions with 100m~ accuracy and monitor them. Is there a way to have the device notify my backend whenever the user enters/exits a region? And would it work even if the app is terminated by the user? (assuming I have the always permission).

Comment: if app is terminated, there is no way. as for the first question, send a API hit whenever you exit

Comment: "For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the user." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion: Is it outdated? If NOT then can I just send an API hit to achieve what I want? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app, these two delegates come when I enter or exit a region.

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion){

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion){

}
```

But be sure to give Always Authorization as said in the above comment

```
override init() {
       super.init()
         if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But just to make sure, is it triggered even if the user kills the app before it happens? And can you send http requests when it is launched in the background?

Comment: http requests yes but after killed app i am not sure.